# Update the value of a field defined in the parent class Entity on an instance of child Entity

Tags: mysql, jpa, netbeans

I have this situation:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="tipo", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.CHAR, length=1)
public class Utente implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 5)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 5)
    private String cap;
...

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="C")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
public class Cliente extends Utente implements Serializable {
...
```

I would change the field "Cap" in an instance of Cliente but when I try to do:

```
Utente u=utenteFacade.find(id);
u.setCap("88888");
utenteFacade.edit(u);
```

or

```
Cliente c=clienteFacade.find(id);
c.setCap("88888");
clienteFacade.edit(u);
```

but the result don't change

I receive an Exception:
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'preUpdate'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.

If I modify the definition of the entity class like here down utenteFacade.edit(u) works well

```
@Entity
public class Utente implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 5)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 5)
        private String cap;
    ...

    @Entity
    public class Cliente implements Serializable {
    ...
```

Comment: The code you've shown deals with Utente - how does Cliente play into it?  Is the returned 'u' an instance of Cliente?  If so, does the validation check work when changing Utente instances to this same value?  What is the utente you pass into utenteFacade.edit(utente);?

Comment: yes, 'u' is an instance of Cliente and then this can be used like Cliente or like the its supertype Utente, e the third line is utenteFacade.edit(u). I don't have instances of Utente but instances of Cliente, Dipendente, ....
Cliente, Dipendente, and the other subtype are specializations of Utente.

I have tried to do edit of supertype Utente, and also the subtype Cliente, but the result don't change

Comment: So the problem then doesn't have to do with inheritance - you can simplify your model to see what might be related to the issue.  Stripping down your test to the minimum that causes the issue will help you get an answer faster.  What does utenteFacade.edit do?

Comment: Thanks a million Chris, for the support but I think the problem is tied with the inheritance.
If I modify the definition of the entity class like here down utenteFacade.edit(u) works well